# How do I parse values from a controller back to yaml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a form in my application.html.erb:

```
 <%=form_tag("/parse_input", method: "post") do %>
        <%= text_field(:ans, :field) %>
        <%= text_field(:ans1, :field) %>
        <%= text_field(:ans2, :field) %>
        <%= submit_tag("submit") %>
    <%end%>

    <%= @ans.to_s %>
```

which is parsed in form_controller.rb:

```
class FormController < ApplicationController
  def parse_input
    params[:ans].each do |value|
      render :template => "layouts/application.html.erb", :locals => {value => value.upcase}
    end
  end
end
```

I want to write the form values to a YAML file. I set up a dummy function in my application.html.erb that successfully generates a YAML from a hash. How do I generate a YAML with the form values?

Comment: `params.to_yaml`?

Comment: @iceman does this actually generate a file? I need those params in a file that I can push to git later on.

Comment: No, not to a file, but that's very easy with ruby

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Show us your attempt to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use Ruby [File](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/File.html).

Add `File.open()` in your controller `parse_input` action<sup>1</sup>:

```
File.open(Rails.root.join('data', 'answers.yaml'), 'a') do |file|
  file << params.to_yaml
end
```

This code will create an `answers.yaml` file in `/data` directory<sup>2</sup> (check `open` options [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode)) and append all your `params` to it (in **yaml** format).

Consider that `params.to_yaml` will include **all** parameters in `params`, so your file will look something similar to this:

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  utf8: "✓"
  authenticity_token: fdUblOU+QL/daIdRoa94IbOjm0RWL/ugABsEYsdfem/Pt+N5hCSMQpfMVWanfqCHoX4WDPfTEUuVsNSJsnuvyQ==
  ans: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    field: answer1
  ans1: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    field: answer2
  ans2: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    field: answer3
  commit: submit
  controller: form
  action: parse_input
permitted: false
```

So you may want to filter `params` before creating the file, and you can accomplish that by, first, changing how you name your `input` tags:

```
<%=form_tag("/parse_input", method: "post") do %>
  <%= text_field(:answers, :ans1) %>
  <%= text_field(:answers, :ans2) %>
  <%= text_field(:answers, :ans3) %>
  <%= submit_tag("submit") %>
<%end%>
```

This will generate a form which `input` names will be grouped in `answers`, for example, the first input `name` will be `answers[ans1]`.

Now you can access only the `answers` parameters with `params[:answers]` (this will filter out anything out of that group, e.g. `commit`, `controller`, `action`, etc.); but we still need more filtering, since `params[:answers].to_yaml` will output:

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  ans1: answer1
  ans2: answer2
  ans3: answer3
permitted: false
```

So, as second step, call `as_json` before calling `to_yaml`; this will convert the `ActionController::Parameters` object to `json` format, removing the extra parameters (i.e. `parameters`, `permitted`), so

```
File.open(Rails.root.join('data', 'answers.yaml'), 'a') do |file|
  file << params[:answers].as_json.to_yaml
end
```

will create the following `answers.yaml` file;

```
---
ans1: answer1
ans2: answer2
ans3: answer3
```

**Notes**

<sup>1</sup> It could be better if you create a private method within your controller, and call that method in your action.

<sup>2</sup> The directory you choose (`data` in the example) should be created first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Everything works, except that the yaml file is blank. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: @JustusP Can you confirm that your `form` parameters are complete? To do that check your logs, you should see something like this: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vQLzPwYZ13iE...", "answers"=>{"ans1"=>"answer1", "ans2"=>"answer2", "ans3"=>"answer3"}, "commit"=>"submit"}`.

Comment: yes
`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YYA6nJoQc08TKVZL....", "answer"=>{"ans1"=>"Test1", "ans2"=>"Test2", "ans3"=>"Test3"}, "commit"=>"submit"}`

Comment: @JustusP Ok, no problem there; can you share your controller action with the updated code (where you are opening the file and reading `params`)?

Comment: `class FormController < ApplicationController
    def parse_input
      # params[:ans].each do |value|
      #   render :template => "layouts/application.html.erb", :locals => {value => value.upcase}
      # end
      File.open(Rails.root.join('lib', 'git', 'quota.yaml'), 'a') do |file|
        file << params[:answers].as_json.to_yaml
      end
    end
end `

Comment: Ohh, i see your key is `answer` not `answers` (i see that typo in my answer as well; so either change to `answer` in your controller: `file << params[:answer].as_json.to_yaml` or change to `:answers` in each input, like this: `<%= text_field(:answers, :ans1) %>`. I've updated the answer (with the second option, that is, changing each input to `:answers`).

Comment: Ohhh! Thanks so much :)

Comment: @JustusP Glad to help! If the answer works you can accept it (clicking the tick) :)

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, assume `params` contains:

```
params = {
  ans: 'foo'
}
```

Use:

```
require 'yaml'

File.write('foo.yaml', params.to_yaml)
```

After running the file would contain:

```
---
:ans: foo
```